# How can I detect if a request and response cookies are different?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, anonymousidentification

I need to detect if a request cookie - value  is different from a response cookie - value.

Its not as easy as:

```
if(cookiesArePresent)
{
    bool isDifferent = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[".ASPXANONYMOUS"].value == HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[".ASPXANONYMOUS"].value;
}
```

But I read that changing the Response.Cookies changes the Request.Cookies. That would mean they are always the same if  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[".ASPXANONYMOUS"] was changed. Is there an easy way around this?

http://chance.lindseydev.com/2009/04/aspnet-httprequestcookies-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Reflector to examing System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, you can see that the anonymous cookie is only read/written in PostAuthenticateRequest.

So, if you suspect something is wonky, write a simple HttpModule that reads the cookie during AuthenticateRequest and compare it to the value you get in AuthorizeRequest.

For more information about the request lifecycle see [Exploring Web.config - system.web/httpModules](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39026/Exploring-Web-config-system-web-httpModules.aspx) by yours truly.